# How can I plot a sum function using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot the following function
`sum a*exp(-0.001*(x-b)**2)` 
where a and b values are listed in the 1st and 2nd columns of an input file respectively, like this

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3

.....
an bn
```

now I am plotting it using the following command

```
plot a1*exp(-0.001*(x-b1)**2) + a2*exp(-0.001*(x-b2)**2) + a1*exp(-0.001*(x-b3)**2) ...etc
```

what I need is a short command to plot all data without writing all the data one by one.

the expected output should be one continuous line like this

[image: the expected output should be one continuous line like this]

Comment: please update your title, it says 'gun' plot, which can be open to interpretation..

Comment: ok done it's my bad

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy, and how should look your expected plot? just points, joined points?

Comment: ok, see the attached figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is probably to use awk to generate the wanted plot command.
For example,

```
f(a,b,x)=a*exp(-0.001*(x-b)**2)
sum(x) = `awk <data '{v = v sprintf("f(%s,%s,x)+",$1,$2)} END{print v "0"}'`
set xrange [250:650]
plot sum(x)
```

This uses backticks inside the gnuplot command file to run awk which reads from the data file and generates a string like:

```
f(1,2,x)+f(3,4,x)+...0
```

where 1,2 3,4 are the first 2 sets of values from the data. 
The gnuplot user-defined function `sum()` is set to this, and you can plot it.

[image]

Comment: this does not give what I want the a*exp(-0.001*(X-b)**2) can be plotted in Gnuplot without defining X, I need to plot the command **{plot a1*exp(-0.001*(x-b1)**2) + a2*exp(-0.001*(x-b2)**2) + a1*exp(-0.001*(x-b3)**2) ...etc}** using short command

Comment: this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like:

with ***gnuplot*** 5.0:

```
gnuplot> set title "sum columns"
gnuplot> set size square
gnuplot> plot 'inputfile' u 1:($1*exp(-0.001*(x-$2)**2)) w linespoints
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: why do you define x? a function <<a1*exp(-0.001*(x-b1)**2)>> doesnot need to define x.

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy, yes, see my update